# Chrome packaged app window, resizes itself when I minimize - then maximize the window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I've built a chrome packaged app and for some reason when I minimize the window and maximize it again, the window size is changed (becomes smaller both width and height)! Looks like when the window is resized, the entire window including the frame changes to the size I wanted only the content to be.

In background.js, I open the window as follows:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function () {
    chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
        id: 'appWindow',
        width: 400,
        height: 520,
        minWidth: 400,
        minHeight: 520,
        maxWidth: 400,
        maxHeight: 520,
        resizable: false
    });
});
```

I've tried using 'bounds' as well (with width/height in it), but it did not help. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you do anything on `onRestored`? If not, this might be a bug. Also note that the `innerBounds` way is the right way, `minWidth` and friends [are deprecated](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#type-CreateWindowOptions).

Comment: I don't even have an 'onRestored' listener. I tried using innerBounds and I get the same issue. You might be right about it being a bug. I wonder if anyone else noticed this.

Comment: Well, search through https://crbug.com and if there's nothing similar - make a new bug report. You might want to make a minimal example for that. Inlcude a link to the report here if you do that.

Comment: Will do. Thanks, Xan.

Comment: I just noticed another weird thing about this. When I move the window, it resizes to the correct size! Aside from reporting this as a bug, maybe I should manually reset the size in 'onRestored'. Is that possible?

Comment: I would try it. Which OS are you talking about, BTW?

Comment: Windows 8.1 64bit. I tried adding the following to my background.js but it didn't show the console.log in either 'Inspect element' console, or 'Inspect background page' console.  chrome.app.window.onRestored.addListener(function () {
    console.log("window restored"); });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64089/discussion-between-nir-and-xan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to fix this 'nicely', but I do have a workaround.

In my app.js (not background.js), I added:

```
chrome.app.window.current().onRestored.addListener(function () {
    chrome.app.window.get('appWindow').outerBounds.setSize(400, 520);
});
```

That resets the window size when restored. I will post a chrome bug for this later on today.

Thanks for the help, Xan.